# Filling html forms with mysql data using php coming up null

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, webserver

I am trying to fill a html form with data being received out of my mysql database. However I cannot set the forms to display on-load the variables being extracted from the database. I would like the form on-load to hold the data last entered into the forms which have been added to the database previously.

```
    $query = "SELECT FROM character_tbl WHERE character_player 

='".$_SESSION["user"]."' character_tbl";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
$name = $row['character_name'];
$race = $row['character_race'];
$class = $row['character_class'];
$alignment = $row['character_alignment'];
$hp = $row['character_hp'];
$str = $row['character_str'];
$dex = $row['character_dex'];
$con = $row['character_con'];
$int = $row['character_int'];
$wis = $row['character_wis'];
$cha = $row['character_cha'];
$ac = $row['character_ac'];
$touch = $row['character_touch'];
$flat = $row['character_flat'];
$fort = $row['character_fort'];
$ref = $row['character_ref'];
$will = $row['character_will'];
}

echo $will;
mysql_close();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="nav">

<form action="user.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
</div>

<div id="section">
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
  Character Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <br>
  Race<br>
  <input type="text" name="race" value="<?php echo $race;?>">
  <br>
  Class<br>
  <input type="text" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>">
  <br>
  Alignment<br>
  <input type="text" name="alignment" value="<?php echo $alignment;?>">
  <br>
  HP<br>
  <input type="text" name="hp" value="<?php echo $hp;?>">
  <br>
  STR<br>
  <input type="number" name="str" value="<?php echo $str;?>">
  <br>
  DEX<br>
  <input type="number" name="dex" value="<?php echo $dex;?>">
  <br>
  CON<br>
  <input type="text" name="con" value="<?php echo $con;?>">
  <br>
  INT<br>
  <input type="text" name="int" value="<?php echo $int;?>">
  <br>
  WIS<br>
  <input type="text" name="wis" value="<?php echo $wis;?>">
  <br>
  CHA<br>
  <input type="text" name="cha" value="<?php echo $cha;?>">
  <br>
  AC<br>
  <input type="text" name="ac" value="<?php echo $ac;?>">
  <br>
  Touch AC<br>
  <input type="text" name="touch" value="<?php echo $touch;?>">
  <br>
  Flat-Footed AC<br>
  <input type="text" name="flat" value="<?php echo $flat;?>">
  <br>
  Fortitude<br>
  <input type="text" name="fort" value="<?php echo $fort;?>">
  <br>
  Reflex<br>
  <input type="text" name="ref" value="<?php echo $ref;?>">
  <br>
  Will<br>
  <input type="text" name="will" value="<?php echo $will;?>">
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Update">

</form>
```

Comment: Realise that your variables will have the last values of your forloop

Comment: Sorry I do not quite follow, expand?

Comment: Let's say `mysql_fetch_array($result)` has 3 rows, when you do this: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
$name = $row['character_name']; ...` the variable `$name` gets the value of `$row['character_name']` 3 times and they are overriding each other, therefore, in the end you will end up **only** with the value of last (here 3rd) row.

Comment: It should only be fetching one row though, since I set it up that only one user can have an entry in their session name.

Comment: In this case yes but beware of this as a general practice :). By the way I personally, haven't quite understood what your question is. To me, the is page is refreshing and naturally you lost your previous values

Comment: I am trying to fill the form with values taken out of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your mysql query. You have not place field or columns name or (`*`) for all columns to extract.

Try like this..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM character_tbl WHERE character_player ='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: what is the ouput of var_dump($row); and echo $_SESSION["user"];

Comment: I placed it underneath the while loop and got no output?

Comment: did you check the value is set in $_SESSION["user"] or not?

Comment: print and see the query echo $query;

Comment: I am seeing no output doing that as well.

Comment: and echo $_SESSION["user"]; is not printing anything either? Why can I not echo anything.

Comment: I am seeing all my web forms, and it is saying
Connected successfully
Table created successfully
but not seeing any other echos I place

Comment: just put session_start(); on top after php tag start then check echo $_SESSION["user"]; is showing its value or not

Comment: It is not, however wouldnt that mean it would redirect since I have this:

`session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) == "test" && isset($_SESSION["pswrd"]) == "test") { //tests for logged in session
 }
 else
 {
  header( 'Location: index.php' ); //else sends to login page
 }`

Comment: okay, I got it to echo my session name now, it is doing that correctly.

Comment: and var_dump returns NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101578/discussion-between-amit-rajput-and-zoid230).

Answer (score 1):

I think the SQL has error:

```
SELECT FROM character_tbl WHERE character_player
```

try:

```
SELECT * FROM character_tbl WHERE character_player
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: use "while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){"  instead of "while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){" -------see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: and you can use var_dump($row);exit; to confirm the data is right

Comment: I get NULL doing var_dump, does that mean there is something wrong with me inserting the data?

Comment: use var_dump under while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ？

Comment: you need to check out the database